# Why doesn't this js array function work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm using the jQuery library, and attempting to push items to an array:

`< onclick ="setFacet('myarray','val');">AOC`

```
var myarray = [];

function setFacet(arr, bb) {
    for (var i=0; i< arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i] == bb) 
            return true;

    arr.push(bb);
    return false;
}
```

I get this in chrome:

Object myarray has no method 'push'

Comment: Your indentation makes the code hard to read.

Comment: Shouldn't you be pushing into `myarray` and not `arr`?

Comment: Also, what exactly doesn't work? Do you get an error message or something?

Comment: Where exactly does jQuery come into the picture?

Comment: @JosephSilber: It's an SO question; you have to mention jQuery to be trendy ;)

Comment: @TikhonJelvis - You and I both know you were being sarcastic, but others won't. This behavior should really be discouraged. I changed the tags.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: I cleaned it up a little

Comment: @TikhonJelvis jQuery hater ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, I think I found the issue. In your `onclick`, you're calling the function with two *strings*. The first argument should be an array rather than `'myarray'`.

If you just get rid of the quotes (and if `myArray` is in the global scope) it should work. That is, have it look like this:

```
onclick="setFacet(myArray, 'val')"
```

Comment: How Can I reference an array inside the onclick?

Comment: Assuming `myArray` is a global variable, you should be able to just do `onclick="setFacet(myArray, 'val')"`.

Answer (score 2):

**Change:**

`onclick="setFacet('myarray','val')"`

**To:**

`onclick="setFacet(myarray)"`

then change the function `setFacet` to the following:

```
function setFacet(arr, bb) {
   for (var i=0; i< arr.length; i++)
       if (arr[i] == bb) return true;

   arr.push(this.innerHTML); /* "this" in the context of the "click" */
                             /* is the element clicked */

   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the element with the onclick listener should be

```
<...onclick ="setFacet(myarray,'val');">
```

myarray should not be quoted, otherwise it will be treated as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could separate your javascript from your markup altogether and just store the value as an attribute of the clicked element (or any other element)

```
<input type="button" value="someValue">

<script>
  $(function(){
    var myArray = [];

    $('#myEle').click(function(){
      myArray.push($(this).val())
    })
  })
</script>
```